# File:/// formula field not rendering url in hyperlink for a user

Tags: lightning, formula

I have a user with issues (maybe after Spring '20?) with a hyperlink formula.

Formula is a simple text output type of the form:

> HYPERLINK ("file:///bob.txt" , "TEST")

The different output HTML is shown below for a user where this works, and one that doesn't. Notice the completely different tags and structure.

Working:

```
<span class="test-id__field-value slds-form-element__static slds-grow  is-read-only" data-aura-rendered-by="2729:7288;a">
    <span class="lvm-grid-no-fade-out undefined forceOutputFormulaHtml" data-aura-rendered-by="2720:7288;a" data-aura-class="forceOutputFormulaHtml">
        <a href=“file:///Bob.txt” target="_blank" data-aura-rendered-by="2721:7288;a">TEST</a>
     </span>
</span>
```

Broken:

```
<formula-output-formula-html formula-outputformulahtml_outputformulahtml-host="">
          <lightning-formatted-rich-text formula-outputformulahtml_outputformulahtml="" class="slds-rich-text-editor__output"> 
              <span>
                 <a target="_blank">TEST</a>
              </span>
           </lightning-formatted-rich-text>
    </formula-output-formula-html>
```

This user can switch to another user and see the link working fine (so not obviously a browser issue) and other working users can switch to this user and its broken. This occurs on different objects and page layouts so not limited to one usecase.

SF support have been 'worse than useless' on this so reaching out to see if this has been seen and maybe sorted out before.

Could it be an issue with the user record? Can't see anything that would affect this.

Any help much appreciated.

Rich.

Comment: I'm not really following what's the exact issue.  For what it's worth, `<a target="_blank">TEST</a>` doesn't have an `href`

Comment: The issue is a formula field doesn't render properly (as you say, the href is missing) for a user. The output is in the standard 'view record' pages for both classic and lightning. Just broken for this user...

Comment: @RichardDurrant check if this could be related to the Spring 20 critical update which should be activated [Open Hyperlinks in Formula Fields Correctly](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_honor_target_value_formula_fields.htm)

Comment: @Shamina No it's not related to this release.